# How to extract numbers from string using regular expression in Python except when within brackets?

Tags: python, regex

Here are my test strings:

- Word word word; **123-125**
- Word word (1000-1000)
- Word word word (1000-1000); **99-999**
- Word word word word

What regular expression should I use to **extract only those numbers (format: `\d+-\d+`) that are not within brackets** (the ones in bold above)?

I've tried this:

```
(\d+-\d+)(?!\))
```

But it's matching:

- Word word word; **123-125**
- Word word (**1000-100**0)
- Word word word (**1000-100**0); **99-999**
- Word word word word

Note the last digit before the second bracket.

I was trying to drop any match that is followed by a bracket, but it's only dropping one digit rather than the whole match! What am I missing here?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead to get only those values you need like this:

```
(?![^()]*\))(\d+-\d+)
```

The `(?![^()]*\))` look-ahead actually checks that there are no closing round brackets after the hyphenated numbers.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aN5wN1/1)

Sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?![^()]*\))(\d+-\d+)')
test_str = u"Word word word; 123-125\nWord word (1000-1000)\nWord word word (1000-1000); 99-999\nWord word word word"
re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Output of the [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdFJUcUZoZ1FrOVE):

```
[u'123-125', u'99-999']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete answer! Much appreciated. Could you explain what is the function of the following part, please? `[^()]*`

Comment: `[^()]*` is a negated character class that means *match any number of characters other than literal `(` and `)`*.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, @stribizhev. What if I wanted to exclude `\d+-\d+` that come *after* a specific string, like `ABC 1234-1234`, or `ABC: 1234-1234`? I tried this: `(?<!(ABC |ABC: ))(?![^()]*\))(\d+-\d+)` but that didn't work at all. The error I got was: `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`.

Comment: It is not possible to use variable-width look-behind with the standard `re` library. However, in this case, it is possible to use 2: `(?![^()]*\))(?<!ABC )(?<!ABC: )(\d{2}-\d+)`. Mind that here we need to limit the first digits to `{2}`, or we'll still get a match.

Answer (score 2):

A way consists to describe all you don't want:

```
[^(\d]*(?:\([^)]*\)[^(\d]*)*
```

Then you can use an always true assertion: *a digits are always preceded by zero or more characters that are not digits and characters between quotes.*

You only need to capture the digits in a group:

```
p = re.compile(r'[^(\d]*(?:\([^)]*\)[^(\d]*)*(\d+-\d+)')
```

The advantage of this way is that you don't need to test a lookahead at each position in the string, so it is a fast pattern. The inconvenient is that it consumes a little more memory, because the whole match produces more long strings.